# Public API design with out parameter of a structure type containing char *

Tags: c, struct, enums, union, software-design

I'm designing a public platform independent API for event notification and currently have the following interface:

```
enum ns_event_type{
    deleted,
    moved
};

struct ns_event_meta{
    enum ns_event_type type;
    size_t internal_buffer_size;
    void *internal_buffer; /* Memory to store either deleted_path or moved */
    union {
        const char *deleted_path;
        struct {
             const char *moved_from;
             const char *moved_to;
        } moved;
    } event_data;
};

typedef struct ns_event_queue ns_event_queue;

int ns_take_event(ns_event_queue *queue, struct ns_event_meta *meta_out);
```

The way I designed the `struct ns_event_meta` is to contain a buffer of raw memory. The buffer is used as a container for either `const char *readable_path` or (`const char *moved_from` and `const char *moved_to`).

So In case if the `void *interval_buffer` size is not enough to hold path(s) for the event being taken the function `ns_take_event` returns `-1` and the caller is expected to grow `void *internal_buffer;`

The problem I see about this design is that the client of the library can get access to the raw buffer `void *internal_buffer` which is not really intended to be accessed by the client. By contrast, event meta is intended to be examined through member `enum ns_event_type type;` and `event_data`.

Is there another way to approach such a design issue?

Comment: `and the caller is expected to grow void *internal_buffer;` - the whole point in making an opaque design is not to have the caller touch your data. Reallocate the buffer yourself inside `ns_take_event`. Any reason for not having functions like `int ns_event_meta_resize_internal_buffer(ns_event_meta *meta);` and `enum ns_event_type ns_event_mate_get_event(ns_event_meta *meta);` ?

Comment: @KamilCuk I did not intended to make the `struct ns_event_meta` opaque because I expected a caller to have access to members `event_type` and `event_data`. Are you suggesting to make it opaque? Or would it be ok to add a `void *` parameter to the `ns_take_event` function and therefore put the `internal_buffer` out of the struct members?

Comment: To me it's unclear what you are asking. The answer could be: "Let the function do realloc"  but I guess that's not what you are looking for...

Comment: 1. `Are you suggesting to make it opaque?` I'm suggesting to write all the accessor functions the user would need to access your struct. I leave the struct declaration visible anyway, for the reason I want users to be able to allocate the buffer on stack. 2. That depends on the design, ex. if you use `internal_buffer` asynchronously or in that function only....

Comment: Maybe you could put the "private" members into an opaque data type so that the struct seen by the user only holds "public" members and a pointer to the opaque data type. You would then have to provide a number of function to manipulate the opaque data.

Comment: @4386427 _You would then have to provide a number of function to manipulate the opaque data._ That's a good idea I think. So I add sort of `typedef struct ns_event_buffer ns_event_buffer` and 3 function declarations:  `ns_event_buffer_allocate`, `ns_event_buffer_resize`, `ns_event_buffer_delete`. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @St.Antario yes, that's the basic idea. If you want to go one step further to "hide" the real data, you can let the struct contain a handle (i.e. a simple number) instead of an opaque pointer. Then your code would need a table to translate between handles and pointers. In this way the user doesn't even see the address of the "private" data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you have two conflicting requirements.

1. You want the user to allocate memory for the `internal_buffer` (and update `internal_buffer_size` as well, I assume).
2. You want to hide the `internal_buffer` from the user.

You can't do both! If the user is going to handle memory allocation, you can't "hide" the buffer. So either you have to accept that the user knows about the buffer or you have to allocate the memory in your code.

A well known way of hiding internal data is to use an opaque data type. The basic idea is that you gather the private data members in a struct, e.g. `struct private`. The user only gets a pointer to the struct but no information about the contents of the struct. You'll have to provide all functions needed to manipulate the hidden/private data.

It could look something like:

ns_event.h (to be included by users)

```
enum ns_event_type{
    deleted,
    moved
};

struct ns_private;  // Opaque data type. The user knows that this type exists
                    // but have no idea what it contains.

struct ns_event_meta{
    enum ns_event_type type;
    union {
        const char *deleted_path;
        struct {
             const char *moved_from;
             const char *moved_to;
        } moved;
    } event_data;
    struct ns_private *buffer;  // The user only gets a pointer to the
                                // "private" data but can't access the
                                // members as the user doesn't know
                                // what's inside
};

// Public functions
int ns_init_buffer(struct ns_event_meta *buffer, size_t size);    
int ns_resize_buffer(struct ns_event_meta *buffer, size_t size);    
size_t ns_get_buffer_size(struct ns_event_meta *buffer);    
void ns_free_buffer(struct ns_event_meta *buffer);    
...
...
```

ns_event.c (your code)

```
struct ns_private {
    size_t internal_buffer_size;
    void *internal_buffer;
}

int ns_init_buffer(struct ns_event_meta *buffer, size_t size)
{
    assert(buffer != NULL);
    buffer->internal_buffer = malloc(size);
    if (buffer->internal_buffer == NULL)
    {
        buffer->internal_buffer_size = 0;
        return 1;
    }
    buffer->internal_buffer_size = size;
    return 0;
}

...
...
```

You can also use a handle instead of a pointer to the opaque data type. Like

```
struct ns_event_meta{
    enum ns_event_type type;
    union {
        const char *deleted_path;
        struct {
             const char *moved_from;
             const char *moved_to;
        } moved;
    } event_data;
    int handle;    // A handle to hide the location of "private" data
                   // Translation will be needed in the c-file
};
```

The `handle` would just be an integer selected by your code in a `ns_init_buffer` call. Inside your code you'll have a table that translate between handle numbers and pointers to the private data. In this way the user will never know where the private data is stored and will not even know the name of the struct holding the private data.

note: storing the handle inside the struct is matter of taste. You could remove it from the struct and let init-function return the handle. The user would then have to store the handle in some other variable and pass it as an extra function argument.